# UIviewcontroller size issue in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIviewcontroller`  in a navigation based project, to which i am pushing some views as a result of some button action.

When I first load this view, its size is showing `(0,0,320,416)` in the `viewwillappear` method. But, if you run it again, its size is showing `(0,0,320,460)` in the same `viewwillappear` method. My view is seems to be resizing when you load it again.

Due to that I have so many problems in the pushed view. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: i am sure that i was not setting the view manually anywhere in my code

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's almost impossible to debug such issues without seeing your code.

Comment: i am pushing my viewcontroller to the navigationcontroller from an nsobject class .can we able to do that?is that the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(0,0,320,416) is - 20 for status bar and - 44 for navigation bar and (0,0,320,460) is just the -20 for the status bar, perhaps your navigation bar is translucent?.

Comment: am pushing my viewcontroller to the navigationcontroller from an nsobject class .can we able to do that?is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

the difference between two sizes is 44 .. which is the height of the navigation bar ,, i think your problem in the navigation controller or you are set it translucent.

Comment: am pushing my viewcontroller to the navigationcontroller from an nsobject class .can we able to do that?is that the issue?